# Preventing scroll in scrollview with YUI3

Tags: javascript, yui

I am using the scrollview to contain a group of div widgets. So, that many widgets may be contained in a small area yet usable. However, the form dropdown input seems to be buggy/ completely messed up because it wants to scroll with it. In Firefox I have to right click then select for it to pick anything and in chrome it just blacks out the div until I select something and it all comes flying back. Is there a way for me to tell YUI to not scroll when selecting a form?

Thanks.

Comment: No offense, I find this very unclear. You dont want to have us read it 3x and still we dont know what you mean. Could you add a screenshot or jsfiddle/example?

Comment: I decided to just do a YUI menu drop down and it worked. I was using a HTML drop down to select a form input but the scrollview was preventing the selection (as it would do a mousedown and start scrolling) I am putting divs inside of a scrollview.